# Error array property not found in Angular Loop

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, angularjs-directive, ngfor

Not able to use property of Array which exists in array for showing data

[image]

Error in accessing the property

[image]

Assigning the values to array
[image]

Error on Page
[image]

I want to access the property in loop which will display the category name

Comment: Please don’t make people click 4 links just to understand if they can help you. Include code *here*

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```
category?.data?.category
```

It will check if the property exist then only render.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone and got solution by changing array declaration to any instead of object.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).